# Error when running app after building: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, enterprise-library, .net-assembly

I have an asp.net application, when I build the application and then run it I get the following server error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Source Error:

Line 25:     <form id="form1" runat="server" dir="rtl" >
Line 26:     <div>
Line 27:     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="3600" >
Line 28:       <Services>
Line 29:        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/myService.asmx" InlineScript="true"/>
```

this happend in the first time I run the application after building, if I refresh the page in the browser or run it again without rebuild I don't get the error.
Does any one have an idea why this happend and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the last recommendation by the editor here: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/363098